# How to reuse the same view in different projects?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, composite-component

I'm pretty new in JSF usage and yet don't know how to use JSF correctly in some cases. So,

***The problem:*** Reusing the same view in a different JSF-projects.

I have three completely separated projects (call them `A`, `B` and `C` to be more specifiec) having a web-page providing the information about user-groups, stored in a database. The users in the project `A` called players, in the project `B` partners and in the project `C` visitors. The web-pages in all those project are the same except the title (players, partners and visitors). So, now I have a lot of code dupes (three almost the same `facelet`s in those projects.

Is it appropriate to put the facelet in a jar-file and use `ui:include` as follows:

The project `A`

```
<ui:inlude src="shared/xhtmlpage.xhtml" >
    <ui:param name="title" value="Players" />
</ui:inlude>
```

The project `B`

```
<ui:inlude src="shared/xhtmlpage.xhtml">
    <ui:param name="title" value="Players" />
</ui:inlude>
```

and so forth...

Or it would be better to use a composite component, I mean, incapsulate the web-page within a ***composite*** component, called, say `myns:userInfo` with an attribute `userTitle`, so we could use it as follows:

```
<myns:userInfo userTitle="Players" />
```

and so forth...

Answer (score 0):

You might want to save that view in a specific file and then transfer it accordingly to your new project.

Comment: What do you mean? I don't want to have three almost the same facelets in those projects. How can I avoid it?

Comment: Can't make any sense of this "answer". It looks much like you have no idea what OP is concretely asking.